# Was Saruman truly a puppet?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

This quote got me thinking:

> The world is changing. Who now has the strength to stand against the armies of Isengard... and Mordor? To stand against the might of Sauron and Saruman... and the union of the Two Towers? Together, my Lord Sauron, we shall rule this Middle-earth.

### Question

Is there any canonical evidence that would support Saruman's assertion that he would be a joint ruler (alongside Sauron) over Middle-earth and not just a puppet as Gandalf and others presumed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did Sauron give any care to Saruman or was he just a pawn?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/did-sauron-give-any-care-to-saruman-or-was-he-just-a-pawn)

Comment: And yet Isengard by itself got picked off relatively easily by Rohan and a small Elvish army.  I'd say the "union of the Two Towers" wouldn't have been significantly stronger than Mordor alone. Saruman was ignorant or had an overinflated ego, take your pick.

Comment: @chepner The Elves that were only there in the movie?  You are also leaving out the Ents, who were fairly significant there.

Comment: @suchiuomizu Yes; the movie-Saruman was far more cartoonishly ridiculous than book-Saruman.